# find max/ min in int array structure in ml

Tags: sml

Im new in ML and I am having quite a hard time trying to extract the min or max of an array of integers.
I have created the array from a list of integers using [`Array.fromList`](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/array.html#SIG%3aARRAY.fromList%3aVAL).

A hint could be very useful since functions like hd, or tl do not work on arrays

Comment: Maybe use `Array.iter (fun i -> if i > !max_i then max_i := i else ()) arr`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated you have basically the same functionality in SML.
When working on arrays instead of lists, you have to use functions that takes an array as input, and not a list. Kind of goes without saying.

Basically you can solve the problem the same way you would, if it was a regular list. However you just need to use the folding functionality from the Array module. Unlike regular lists, we can't pattern match them to decompose it into the first element and the rest of the list, so we must select the first element through the [`sub`](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/array.html#SIG%3aARRAY.sub%3aVAL) function. To make sure that there are elements in the list, you can wrap it with a test that compares the [`length`](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/array.html#SIG%3aARRAY.length%3aVAL) of the array.

```
fun min_arr arr = Array.foldl Int.min (Array.sub (arr, 0)) arr


- val a = Array.fromList [5,76,2,6,8,2,3,7,81,3];
val a = [|5,76,2,6,8,2,3,7,81,3|] : int array
- min_arr a;
val it = 2 : int
```

To find the biggest element in the list, you could exchange the `Int.min` function with `Int.max`.

Answer (score 3):

In OCaml:

```
let min_array arr = Array.fold_left min arr.(0) arr
```

This code uses `arr.(0)` as an initial candidate for minimum value, and fails if the array is empty, so you may want to check for that or use a domain-specific initial candidate that is always bigger than the real minimum (I'm personally wary of using `max_int` in these situations).

I see that SML has a `foldl` function that allows to do the same thing. I'll let you adapt the syntax as needed.